# Insert PHP within function

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a child theme in WordPress and I want to insert this code at the end of each single post:

```
<?php the_tags(); ?>
```

I don't want to edit single.php. I would like to insert this code via functions.php

I found this thread and used the code in this answer: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/insert-info-into-bottom-of-posts#post-3990037

It worked well for me, but I cannot figure out how to insert my PHP code.

These are the things I tried but didn't reflect what I wanted in the front end:

```
$content.= '<?php the_tags(); ?>';

$content.= ' the_tags();';

$content.= <?php the_tags(); ?>;

$content.= the_tags();
```

How can I alter the code in that WordPress thread to include php?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attempting to concatenate the output of `the_tags` onto `$content`, but `the_tags` does not return anything. When you call `the_tags` it sends output to the browser itself.

`the_tags` is pretty much just a wrapper around `get_the_tag_list` which does return content as a string rather than outputting it. Try:

```
$content .= get_the_tag_list();
```

Also, just to clarify exactly what is wrong with some of your attempts:

```
$content.= <?php the_tags(); ?>;
```

`<?php` essentially means *begin interpreting PHP*, at this point I'm assuming you have already opened your PHP tags so there is no need to do it again and attempting to do so will result in an error.

```
$content.= ' the_tags();';
```

This will append the literal string `the_tags();` onto `$content`. You cannot embed function calls into strings like this.

```
$content.= '<?php the_tags(); ?>';
```

This last line is just a combination of the two issues I just mentioned. It will result in the literal string `<?php the_tags(); ?>` being appended to `$content`.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the explanation on why my code was wrong! I am very interested in learning how PHP works as I go along. I tried inputting $content .= get_the_tag_list(); and it doesn't seem to have worked. I also tried $content .= get_the_tags(); and that didn't work either. Any ideas?

Comment: Oh my gosh. I went to do that when I realized I had commented out my code right before I posted on SE because I didn't want anything to reflect on the front end. Your code worked!! Thanks so much.

Comment: No problem! Anteaters > Banana Slugs ;D

Comment: Uh, I don't think so! :)